# kernel panic not syncing on a VM, fresh ISO which works on other machines

Tags: server, 22.04

I'm trying to install 22.04 Server, the ISO I uploaded to my hosting provider successfully worked with 2 other instances, but this one is making problems:

[image]

Comment: Is it a 32 bit processor emulated? It probably won't work with 64 bit binaries.

Comment: It's 64 Bit I just checked

Comment: It states: Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FS + PIIX, 1996). It says i440FS chipset supports Pentium Pro and Pentium II processors. I don't think they are 64 bit.

Comment: Huh, thats weird, because 20.04 did run, and afaik that one doesn't support 32 bit anymore :shrug:

Comment: Then, is it possible to upgrade your QEMU hardware? I think it helps.